# Crossout whole row

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I try crossout row in table. Line must be over all cells in center vertical.
So I add new shape to cell, like this:

```
var cell = node as Cell;
var width = cell.CellFormat.Width;

var line = new Shape(args.Document, ShapeType.Line);
line.Width = width;
line.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
line.RelativeVerticalPosition = RelativeVerticalPosition.Paragraph;
line.Top = 5;
line.BehindText = true;
line.WrapType = WrapType.None;

line.StrokeColor = Color.Black;

line.Stroke.LineStyle = ShapeLineStyle.Single;

line.StrokeWeight = 1;
_builder.MoveTo(cell.LastParagraph);
_builder.InsertNode(line);
```

But this work only when I have single text line in cell, if is two or more line text, my crossout line is not center: 
[image]

How fix it? 

Maybe is other solution for crossout whole row?

Comment: I have never seen aspose but I assume your problem is `RelativeVerticalPosition.Paragraph` - have you tried using something else?

Comment: @mihail Yes, i try all enum values and result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can build logic on the following code that inserts a full-width Line Shape at the middle of each Cell in Table.

```
Document doc = new Document("E:\\temp\\in.docx");
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

LayoutCollector collector = new LayoutCollector(doc);
LayoutEnumerator enumerator = new LayoutEnumerator(doc);

foreach (Table table in doc.FirstSection.Body.Tables)
{
    foreach (Row row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            enumerator.Current = collector.GetEntity(cell.FirstParagraph);
            while (enumerator.Type != LayoutEntityType.Cell)
            {
                enumerator.MoveParent();
            }

            double top = enumerator.Rectangle.Top + (enumerator.Rectangle.Height / 2);
            double left = enumerator.Rectangle.Left;
            double width = enumerator.Rectangle.Width;

            builder.MoveTo(table.NextSibling);

            Shape line = builder.InsertShape(ShapeType.Line, width, 0);
            line.Top = top;
            line.Left = left;

            line.RelativeHorizontalPosition = RelativeHorizontalPosition.Page;
            line.RelativeVerticalPosition = RelativeVerticalPosition.Page;

            line.BehindText = true;
            line.WrapType = WrapType.None;
            line.StrokeColor = Color.Blue;
            line.Stroke.LineStyle = ShapeLineStyle.Single;
            line.StrokeWeight = 1;
        }
    }
}

doc.Save("E:\\temp\\19.1.docx");
```

Hope, this help. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.